# cannot get bash readline incremental undo to work

Tags: readline

First question ever and it's pretty simple. I've been reading about readline shortcuts in bash terminal, but I **cannot get the incremental undo to work** with Ctrl+_, Ctrl+x, or Ctrl+u as documented for bash.

I'm using CentOS 7 and echo $0 indicates I'm using bash shell. Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so, first  of all, i now realize my question was poor (i.e. what bash shell in what os?) . . . but turns out that shortcuts do care about flavor of linux and bash in centos is not exactly the same as bash in WSL on Windows 10 (obviously since that's ubuntu by default)

but the most embarassing part is that the Ctrl+_ shortcut in particular was not working because the underline requires a shift . . . oy . . .

Comment: Regarding the other keys, I believe it is supposed to be a sequence: Ctrl+x, then Ctrl+u.